Regrading sitemap and canonical urls and locales in general of nextjs 14
I'm building a website that has three locales: en-US, en-GB, and en-NZ.
Now that I'm using the middleware of Nextjs, my default locale is en-US, so whenever the user's browser doesn't have any access again, rather than these 3 locales, the middleware will put en-US after the base URL.
So my question is: What will be the structure of the sitemap right now? What I am doing is 
   
 <url>
    <loc>https://www.simple.com/en-US"</loc>
    <xhtml:link
      rel="alternate"
      hreflang="en-US"
      href="https://www.simple.com/en-US" />
    <xhtml:link
      rel="alternate"
      hreflang="en-GB"
      href="https://www.simple.com/en-GB" />
    <xhtml:link
      rel="alternate"
      hreflang="en-NZ"
      href="https://www.simple.com/en-NZ" />
    <lastmod>2022-10-11T12:31:08.081Z</lastmod>
    <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
    <priority>1</priority>
  </url>

So do I need to add locale in my loc as my default locale is en-US, so my basic URL will always be simple/en-US when no matching locale is already defined?
And if I'm using Google Search Console, then what will be canonical for this URL and other pages? Do I need to add locales in that too?
